# Call to contract doesn't work when sending a merkle proof (using ethers & JS)

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, react

I basically have a contract whose mint function looks like this:

```
    function mint(uint256 _mintAmount, bytes32[] calldata merkleProof) public payable isValidMerkleProof(merkleProof, whitelistMerkleRoot) {
        require(!paused, 'Contract is paused');
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        require(totalSupply() + _mintAmount <= maxSupply, 'Supply minted');
        require(_mintAmount > 0, 'You have to mint at least one');
        require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount, 'You can mint up to 3');

        if (msg.sender != owner()) {
            uint256 senderMintCount = addressMintedBalance[msg.sender];
            require(senderMintCount + _mintAmount <= nftPerAddressLimit, "cannot mint more than 3");
        }

        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
            addressMintedBalance[msg.sender]++;
            _safeMint(msg.sender, supply + i);
        }

    }

    
    // Merkle proof
    modifier isValidMerkleProof(bytes32[] calldata merkleProof, bytes32 root) {
        if(msg.sender != owner()){
            require(MerkleProof.verify(merkleProof, root, keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender))), "Address does not exist in list");
        }
        _;
    }
```

As you can see, it requires the mint amount and the merkle proof to be able to mint.

I then have a React app that looks like this

```
    const proof = mtProof(accounts[0]); //Returns proof from merkletreejs getHexproof()
    

    const isValid = mtValid(accounts[0]);

    async function handleMint() {
        if (window.ethereum) {
            const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
            const signer = provider.getSigner();
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(
                NFTAddress,
                NFT.abi,
                signer
            );
             
            try {
                const response = await contract.mint(BigNumber.from(mintAmount), proof, {
                    value: ethers.utils.parseEther((0.01 * mintAmount).toString()),
                });
                console.log('response: ', response)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error: ", error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Whenever I try to mint with the owner account it works. **PROBLEM IS**, when it is not the owner for some reason it doesn't allow me to mint. App simply won't do nothing.

I have verified that proof is good, as the Mint button will only appear if the account is inside the MerkleTree... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it:

By taking out the comma in the end of the

```
ethers.utils.parseEther((0.01 * mintAmount).toString()),});
```

That last comma, now it looks like this:

```
    const response = await contract.mint(BigNumber.from(mintAmount), proof, {
                value: ethers.utils.parseEther((0.01 * mintAmount).toString())
            });
```

Don't even ask me why or how, cause idk either... fut it fixed it

Comment: The extra comma might have confused how the parameters were packaged for the Ethereum transaction, possibly leading to incorrect execution of the mint function for non-owner accounts. Removing the comma in the code enabled non-owner accounts to successfully mint NFTs alongside the owner.